# Eliminatiing root element from the tree like represented data

Tags: javascript, json, higher-order-functions

I have list of menus queried from the DB, "sample" as follows:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Main Menu', branch: 1, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Main Menu 2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Sub Menu 1-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 1 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sub Menu 2-1', branch: 2, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 7, name: 'Sub Menu 2-2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 },
]
```

So, every menu has branch subbranch1 subbranch2 value which denotes its position in Menu Listing. Menu here can be clickable or just the group-heading-menu for grouping of menus(havings its child).
e.g., Menu with id 1 has 3,4 inside it as its submenu1
also, Menu with id 4 has 5 inside it as its submenu2.

How can i find out find out all the menus which doesnt have any child(or simply a clickable menu not a group-menu).

So , final result for the "given sample" should be like

```
 [
  { id: 3, name: 'Sub Menu 1-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 1 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sub Menu 2-1', branch: 2, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
  { id: 7, name: 'Sub Menu 2-2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 },
]
```

Comment: Can you change the data structure in db? Sure be easier if children just had a parent_Id

Comment: i have sql database structure and normalization is not making much sense for the kind of application domain we are working for. So, will stick with the current structure itself

Comment: Fine...good luck parsing it. Hard to believe you have that many items that modifying one field would take more than a few minutes. Logic needed for what you are trying to do would make it a much simpler array filter which right now is tricky. With a simple parent ID matching child to parent is ultra simple. Also easy to extract in a user interface if you need to have an admin for this menu

Answer (score 3):

You could generate the tree first and then take only the deepest nodes as result.

1. Generate tree

   - Take all level keys in on array to make it iterable.
   - Iterate all nodes and build deeper objects for every found nested node.
   - Assign the node to property `_`.
2. Get deepest nodes

   - Get the keys of the object.
   - Iterate the keys.

     - Check if the key is `_`, then leave the actual iteration.
     - Check if the property has a key length of one and if the key is `_`, then the deepest node is found. Take the undescore propery for the node collection. Leave the iteration.
     - Otherwise try to get the deepest node from the actual key.
3. Return result.

```js
function getDeepestNodes(nodes) {

    function getDeepest(node) {
        Object.keys(node).forEach(function (key) {
            if (key === '_') {
                return;
            }
            if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 1 && '_' in node[key]) {
                result.push(node[key]._);
                return;
            }
            getDeepest(node[key]);
        });
    }

    var levels = ['branch', 'subbranch1', 'subbranch2'],
        tree = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        var temp = tree;
        levels.every(function (level, i, ll) {
            temp[node[level]] = temp[node[level]] || {};
            temp = temp[node[level]]
            return node[ll[i + 1]];
        });
        temp._ = node;
    });

    getDeepest(tree);

    return result;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Main Menu', branch: 1, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 }, { id: 2, name: 'Main Menu 2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 }, { id: 3, name: 'Sub Menu 1-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 }, { id: 4, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 }, { id: 5, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 1 }, { id: 6, name: 'Sub Menu 2-1', branch: 2, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 }, { id: 7, name: 'Sub Menu 2-2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 }],
    result = getDeepestNodes(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very complex nested loop testing structure. If each line referenced the id of it's immediate parent menu, iteration and testing would be trivial. It is assumed that this is the menu structure you are describing:

```
+-------------+
|  Main Menu  |
+-------------+
  +--------------+
  | Sub Menu 1-1 |
  +--------------+
  | Sub Menu 1-2 |
  +--------------+
    +----------------+
    | Sub Menu 1-2-1 |
    +----------------+
+-------------+
| Main Menu 2 |
+-------------+
  +--------------+
  | Sub Menu 2-1 |
  +--------------+
  | Sub Menu 2-2 |
  +--------------+
```

To solve this, you would need to do something like this:

```
old=<original array>
new= new array()
for (z=0;z<old.length;z++) // Loop through each line
{
    linkonly = 1 // Using this prevents multiple 
    if (old[z].subbranch2 == 0) // If this is 3rd level, there is not sub menu
    {
        for (y=0;y<old.length;y++) // Loop through each line
        {
            if (z!=y )  // Don't check line against itself
            {
                if (old[z].branch == old[y].branch) // If both of these have the same main branch
                {
                    if (old[z].subbranch1 != 0) // If this is a submenu, continue
                    {
                        if (old[z].subbranch1 == old[y].subbranch1) // They are in the same submenu section
                        {
                            if (old[y].subbranch2 != 0) // This is a submenu of the tested parent
                            {
                                linkonly = 0
                                y=old.length
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (old[y].subbranch1 != 0) // This is a submenu of the tested item
                            linkonly = 0
                            y=old.length
                        {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (linkonly == 1)
    {
        // push line into new array
    }
}
// use new array
```

The better way would be to change the starting data structure to something like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Main Menu', parent:0, pos:1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Main Menu 2', parent:0, pos:2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Sub Menu 1-1', parent:1, pos:1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2', parent:0, pos:2 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2-1', parent:4, pos:1 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sub Menu 2-1', parent:2, pos:1 },
  { id: 7, name: 'Sub Menu 2-2', parent:2, pos:2 },
]
```

you could then test it like this:

```
old=<original array>
new= new array()
for (z=0;z<old.length;z++) // Loop through each line
{
    linkonly=1
    for (y=0;y<old.length;y++) // Loop through each line
    {
        if (x!=y) // Don't test against itself
        {
            if (old[y].parent == old[x].id)
            {
                linkonly=0
                y=old.length
            }
        }
    }
    if (linkonly == 1)
    {
        // push line into new array
    }
}
// use new array
```

You could also load the lines in a multi-dimensional array and simply iterate through them and determine if sub menus exist by examining the sub array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function isClickableMenu(menu, menus){
    let noOfBranch;
    let noOfSubbranch2;
    if(menu.subbranch1 === 0){
      noOfBranch = menus.reduce((acc,m)=>{
        return m.branch === menu.branch ? acc + 1 : acc;
       },0);
      return noOfBranch === 1;
    }
    if(menu.subbranch2 === 0){
       noOfSubbranch1 = menus.reduce((acc, m)=>{
          return (m.subbranch1 === menu.subbranch1 && m.branch === menu.branch) ? acc + 1 : acc;
       }, 0);
       return noOfSubbranch1 === 1;
    }
    return true
  }

  function getClickableMenus(menus){
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
      if(isClickableMenu(menus[i], menus)){
       newArray.push(menus[i]);
      }
    }
    return newArray;
  }
  
  const menus = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Main Menu', branch: 1, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Main Menu 2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 0, subbranch2: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Sub Menu 1-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Sub Menu 1-2-1', branch: 1, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: 'Sub Menu 2-1', branch: 2, subbranch1: 1, subbranch2: 0 },
    { id: 7, name: 'Sub Menu 2-2', branch: 2, subbranch1: 2, subbranch2: 0 },
  ];
  
  console.log(getClickableMenus(menus));
```

Found the solution!.. still, there can be room for optimization